# Add values to PHP array only once

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on an assignment involving PHP arrays. There are no databases being used here, so any stored information is stored only in an array called $task_list. When the program first loads, three items are added to the task list array with the following code in my index.php file:

```
$task_list = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tasklist', 
        FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

if ($task_list === NULL) {
    $task_list = array();
    $task_list[] = 'Write chapter';
    $task_list[] = 'Edit chapter';
    $task_list[] = 'Proofread chapter';
}
```

I have an HTML form on a different file, which is the one that the user actually interacts with. The actions on the forms are passed to my index.php file where I have a switch setup to handle each action.

```
switch( $action ) {

    case 'Add Task':
        $new_task = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'newtask');
        if (empty($new_task)) {
            $errors[] = 'The new task cannot be empty.';
        } else {
            array_push($task_list, $new_task);
        }
        break;
    case 'Delete Task':
        $task_index = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'taskid', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if ($task_index === NULL || $task_index === FALSE) {
            $errors[] = 'The task cannot be deleted.';
        } else {
            unset($task_list[$task_index]);
            $task_list = array_values($task_list);
        }
        break;

    case 'Modify Task':
        $task_index = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'taskid', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if ($task_index === NULL || $task_index === FALSE) {
            $errors[] = 'The task cannot be modified.';
        } else {
            $task_to_modify = $task_list[$task_index];
        }
        break;

    case 'Save Changes':
        $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'modifiedtaskid', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        $modified_task = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'modifiedtask');
        if (empty($modified_task)) {
            $errors[] = 'The modified task cannot be empty.';
        } else if ($value === NULL || $value === FALSE) {
            $errors[] = 'The task cannot be modified.';
        } else {
            $task_list[$value] = $modified_task;
            $modified_task = '';
        }
        break;

    case 'Cancel Changes':
        $modified_task = '';
        break;

    case 'Promote Task':
        $task_index = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'taskid', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        if ($task_index === NULL || $task_index === FALSE) {
            $errors[] = 'The task cannot be promoted.';
        } elseif ($task_index == 0) {
            $errors[] = 'You cannot promote the first task.';
        } else {
            $task_value = $task_list[$task_index];
            $prior_task_value = $task_list[$task_index - 1];

            $task_list[$task_index - 1] = $task_value;
            $task_list[$task_index] = $prior_task_value;
            break;
        }

    case 'Sort Tasks':
        sort($task_list);
        break;

    case 'Delete All Tasks':
        if (empty($task_list)) {
            $errors[] = 'The list is already empty.';
        } else {
            foreach ($task_list as $key => $value) {
                unset($task_list[$key]);
            }
            $task_list = array_values($task_list);
        }
        break;
}

include('task_list.php');
```

I am mostly done, but the problem I am having is that I still have to modify the code so that the three tasks: "Write Chapter", "Edit Chapter", and "Proofread Chapter" are ONLY added to the array when the application first loads. The problem I am having is that when I delete all tasks in the list and then add a new task, the original three tasks appear once again, even though they had been previously deleted. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: In case my full code is needed, I pasted index.php here:

http://pastebin.com/h6J7aipi

And task_list.php here:

http://pastebin.com/PkSpC30J

Comment: Use sessions/db/cookies. Something persistent, that allows you to modify it continually.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that. Is there a way that an all values in an array can be deleted without the array being considered null; Or is there a better expression I can use instead of if($task_list === NULL)?

Comment: It's going to be reset every request so it isn't really an option. You need to store it somewhere.